# Angular Page refresh "t is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a problem with refreshing pages.
Actually, this problem occurs only on one page.

My Project:
I'm working on a forum-like website where you can log in, see your own profile, see other user's profiles, and so on.

My Problem:
When I visit someone's profile, everything is fine.
Everything gets loaded and so on.
But when I refresh the page, no data got loaded from the server and
my console shows the error "*ERROR TypeError: t is undefined*".

My visit-profile ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataExchangeService } from "../data-exchange.service";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-visit-profile',
  templateUrl: './visit-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./visit-profile.component.css']
})
export class VisitProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getUser(DataExchangeService.visitedUser);
  }
  //Userdaten
  userId = "";
  username = DataExchangeService.visitedUser;
  vorname = "";
  nachname = "";
  user_status: any;

  follows: any;


  getUser(data: any) {


    var sendData = {
      flag: "getUserData",
      Username: data
    }

    var config = {
      params: sendData
    };
    this.http.get<JSON>("visitProfile", config).subscribe(result => {
      var jas = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))[0];
      this.userId = jas.user_id;
      this.username = jas.username;
      this.vorname = jas.vorname;
      this.nachname = jas.nachname;
      this.user_status = jas.user_status;

    },
      err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      });

    sendData = {
      flag: "getFollows",
      Username: data
    }

    config = {
      params: sendData
    };

    this.http.get("visitProfile", config).subscribe(result => {
      //console.log(result);
      this.follows = result;
    },
      err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      });


  }

  onClickMe() {
    console.log("Followed");
  }


  visitUser(follow: any) {
    DataExchangeService.visitedUser = follow.username;
    this.getUser(DataExchangeService.visitedUser);
  }

}
```

Additional:

From the console error message I could see (if I have seen correctly) that "t" is used somewhere in my "getUser" method (I think internally since didn't make any variable with this name).

"DataExchanceService" is a service that holds the static variable "visitUser".
It's used to hand over the user's username to the visit-provide component so it can load the user's data.
On default the variable is undefined ("static visitedUser: any;").
I already tried to give it a dummy value like "user123", which didn't change anything.

**Edit:**
I found out that "t" seems to belong to my "jas" variable.
I declared "jas" outside of the function and the error changed to
"this.jas is undefined".

It still doesn't work and I still don't know why it's undefined.
I even tried to define it manually at declaration, but no luck.

Comment: How do you run your project? `ng serve`?

Comment: Well the error is saying you are trying to read a value that doesn't exist. you may need to define a default or pass a type. If you are using MS Code you can step through each line as its being processed at page load etc.

Comment: @StPaulis I usually use ng build. I tried ng serve, but the error still occurs.

Comment: I guess that you have this error while you are in production. 

You should get a more specific error if you debug with `ng serve` in Chrome

Comment: @StPaulis Ah, Chromes error message is a bit clearer.
It made me look at my server logs again and I found out that on refresh the http get request delivers nothing from the database, because my "visitProfile" is empty after refresh.

Edit: Oddly it's still undefined, even when I give it a value on declaration.

Comment: On my edit: 
Nvm, I forgot to build after change.
It works if I give my "visitedUser" (not "visitProfile) an existing username on default.
So it should work, if I store the username in the local storage when changing sites and use the storage if the variable itself is empty.

Comment: If I understand well, you figure it out. When asking for something, try to give the maximum info with the minimum words. This thread has become very confusing...

Comment: @StPaulis I'm sorry for that, english is not my native language. 
I will give a proper answer as soon as I made everything run in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my "DataExchangeService.visitedUser" variable get deleted,
whenever I refresh the page. (A bit too obvious, I know..)

Instead of saving the username in a service variable,
I now save it in the local storage.

I replaced

```
this.getUser(DataExchangeService.visitedUser);
```

with

```
this.getUser(localStorage.getItem("visitedUser"));
```

and

```
visitUser(follow: any) {
    DataExchangeService.visitedUser = follow.username;
    this.getUser(DataExchangeService.visitedUser);
  }
```

with

```
visitUser(follow: any) {
    localStorage.setItem('visitedUser', follow.username);
    this.getUser(localStorage.getItem("visitedUser"));
  }
```

And it works fine.